# XACML2: XACML2.0 implementation in java

Tags: java, authorization, xacml, abac, xacml2

I'm writing my master-these and i have some problemes with the PDP evaluation of request. I use sunxacml:2.0 in java. when i define a request and evalue it with PDP the response is NotApplicable but when i define a request and encoding in file and i define another request through the encoding's file, the response of the evaluation for this request is permit or deny.

Question: with sunxacml:2.0, the request should always encoding ? or how can i do it?

```
Resquest request= new Request(Set subjects, Set Resource, Set action, Set environment); request.encoding(FileOutputStream file); pdp.evalue(request)-> response: Notapplicable RequestCtx req=RequestCtx.getInstance(new FileInputStream(file))   pdp.evalue(req)-> response: permit or deniy
```

Comment: Can you post the request and the policy?

Comment: i have define a simple request and a simple pdp in java. You can do:

Comment: i have define a simple request and a simple pdp in java. You can do: ResquestCtx req=new RequestCtx(subjects,resource,action,environment); pdp.evaluete(req);  you can take any Policy with constraint on resource or subject or action. the response is NotApplicable but if you transforme and save in one file : req.ecoding(new FileOutputStream(file)) and RequestCtx req2=RequestCtx.getInstance(FileInputStream(file)) and pdp.evalute(req2) than the response is permit or deny.

Comment: Edit your question to add the policy, request and response

Comment: XACML 2.0 and SunXACML are pretty much obsolete. You should switch to XACML 3.0 for better support from the XACML community. See the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XACML#XACML_Implementations) for XACML-3.0-compliant Java implementations.